# set selected word in bold in html document

Tags: javascript

What I want is that the user can select text in my html document and that the selected text if not already will set to bold. If it is already bold then it would be set back to regular. I found a example on stackoverflow here and wanted to try this out.

This my test code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
   function toggleBold() {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // Non-IE case
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
        document.designMode = "on";
        if (range) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange &&
            document.selection.type != "None") {
        // IE case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("bold", false, null);
    }
}
</script>

<div onselect="toggleBold()">This is a test.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I'm testing this in chrome, safari or whatever nothing happens.

I'm not a javascripter so I don't know how to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer to keep away from the inline JavaScript. Your `toggleBold()` function does work, although it's not actioning upon any event, as `select` event works on mostly elements that are actioned from `<form>` elements.

```
<span>Here is some text</span>

<script>
   /**
    *   Listen for any 'mouseup' event, which is actioned
    *   after the mouse click is released after a selection.
   **/
   window.addEventListener( 'mouseup', toggleBold, false );

   function toggleBold() {
      //Toggle's the text.
   }
</script>
```

#### **Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/QRypZ/

Answer (score 3):

### check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvM3P/1/)

Try `onclick()` function

```
<div onclick="toggleBold()">This is a test.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

onSelect is only defined on input and textarea objects.
Try to use onMouseUp.

```
<div onmouseup="toggleBold()">This is a test.</div>
```

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvM3P/)

Answer (score 1):

Use onMouseUp event

```
<div onMouseUp="toggleBold()">This is a test.</div>
```